# Eclipse is very slow to build a java project with node_modules folder

Tags: java, node.js, eclipse

I have a java project with an attached front end that has a node_modules folder with hundreds of files

since i added it it became super slow on build.
The resources folder where the node_modules folder resides was on the build path, i removed it (after excluding this folder) but i see no change what so ever

Comment: What does the Eclipse Progress report show (in status bar or progress view)?

Comment: It writes Invoking MAven project Builder on '/myProject' and that takes forever